# Lerna publish gets stuck after first package

Tags: javascript, npm, publish, lerna

### Current Behavior

When I run `lerna publish`, it gets stuck after packaging the first package. This is where it gets stuck:

```
lerna WARN ENOLICENSE One way to fix this is to add a LICENSE.md file to the root of this repository.
lerna WARN ENOLICENSE See https://choosealicense.com for additional guidance.
(#########⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠏ publish: verb packed packages/react
```

This line particularly:

```
(#########⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠏ publish: verb packed packages/react
```

### Expected Behavior

It should publish to NPM successfully

#### Failure Logs / Configuration

lerna.json

```json
{
  "packages": [
    "packages/*",
    "docs"
  ],
  "version": "independent",
  "stream": true,
  "hoist": true,
  "command": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "npmClientArgs": ["--no-package-lock"]
    },
    "publish": {
      "ignoreChanges": ["**/stories/**", "**/tests/**"]
    }
  }
}
```

#### Environment

System:
OS: macOS 12.3
CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1 Pro
Binaries:
Node: 14.21.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.2/bin/node
npm: 6.14.17 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.2/bin/npm
Utilities:
Git: 2.32.1 - /usr/bin/git
npmPackages:
lerna: ^5.6.2 => 5.6.2